# Using empty parameters in quoted_parameters(params)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, pg

I have the following code:

```
pg = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
res = pg.execute(query % quoted_parameters(params))
```

This is my pseudoquery:

```
select project_id from projects where client_id in (%{ids})
```

This is are the params:

```
{ :ids => [] }
```

It works fine when there are actual values in the ids array.  However it doesn't seem capable of handling an empty array, I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
```

Since it just puts in an empty string.

By default this works fine:

```
Project.where('client_id in (?)', [])
```

And generates the following query:

```
Project Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE (client_id in (NULL))
```

Is there a way to get the query % quoted_parameters(params) to generate the same query even if the array is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clarification**: Are you trying to manually use the SQL in your app? Or asking how you can accomplish that with AR?

With ActiveRecord you should be able to do:

`Project.where(client_id: ids)`

This will work in a number of situations:

```
Project.where(client_id: [])
=> SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE 1=0

Project.where(client_id: [1])
=> SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."client_id" = 1

Project.where(client_id: [1, 2])
=> SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."client_id" IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: I am indeed trying to manually use the SQL in my app.  As I wrote: when I do it with standard ActiveRecord it works fine, but I'm looking for a way to do it with manual SQL.  The SQL example I wrote is of course an example and not the actual SQL (which is much more complicated).

Comment: Gotcha. Did you define `quoted_parameters`? Or are you referencing it from some module?

Comment: Hi Donald.  Stupid me, I thought the quoted_parameters was something of activerecord but it's not.  I was using the technique described here: http://gmile.me/raw-sql-in-a-rails-project/ and see now that quoted_parameters is a method there.  I can work this out now, should be able to handle the case of an empty array that in that method.

Comment: Cool. I saw that post and wondered if that was the source. Best of luck sorting it out :)